# What could be an equivalent approach to a casex statement from SystemVerilog in C

Tags: c, system-verilog

Some context: I'm currently writing an emulator. I'm trying to implement a decoder with similar behavior such as a 'casex' statement on SystemVerilog.

To give some examples these are some of the instructions.

```c
BNE_ENCODING        0b100011xx
BRK_ENCODING        0b10101100
CMP_ENCODING        0b01110000
DEC_ENCODING        0b1001xxxx
```

What I tried: I tried replacing the x with zeros. But that Didn't work.

I don't understand how to ignore the last bit on C, without creating conflicting case statements. The x represents the ignored bits. I tried to understand a bit of the implementation by looking at the generated RTL output from Quartus(I know RTL has nothing to do with C, it's just to give me an idea of the boolean expressions that I could implement). The decoder is implemented with NOR gates.

Part of the decoder on System Verilog.

```
casex(op)
        8'b100011xx: /* Do something */;
        8'b10101100: /* Do something */;
        8'b01110000: /* Do something */;
        8'b1001xxxx: /* Do something */;
endcase
```

Question: What would be the right approach to implement such a decoder in C? By decoder I mean a switch statement with similar behavior as the Verilog `casex` statement.

Comment: I would like using `if` statements instead if `switch` statememt. Isn't it acceptable?

Comment: @MikeCAT Didn't think about that one. How the implementation would be?

Comment: You just want to ignore bits from the right (less significant)?

Comment: @vmp Yes. So I can decode the instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring some bits can be done by masking them with bitwise AND operation.

```
if ((op & 0xFC) == 0x8C) {
    /* 8'b100011xx */
} else if ((op & 0xFF) == 0xAC) {
    /* 8'b10101100 */
} else if ((op & 0xFF) == 0x70) {
    /* 8'b01110000 */
} else if ((op & 0xF0) == 0x90) {
    /* 8'b1001xxxx */
}
```

If you will stick to use `switch` statement, you can use multiple levels of ones.

```
switch (op & 0xF0) {
    case 0x80: /* 8'b1000xxxx */
        switch (op & 0x0C) {
            case 0x0C: /* 8'bxxxx11xx (8'b100011xx) */
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 0xA0: /* 8'b1010xxxx */
        switch (op & 0x0F) {
            case 0x0C: /* 8'bxxxx1100 (8'b10101100) */
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 0x70: /* 8'b0111xxxx */
        switch (op & 0x0F) {
            case 0x00: /* 8'bxxxx0000 (8'b01110000) */
                break;
        }
        break;
    case 0x90: /* 8'b1001xxxx */
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to implement the wildcards, you can use a chain of `if-else` in which you mask the input in a way that will make the comparison ignore the *don't care* bits:

```
if((op & 0xFC) == 0x8C) // 0x8C = 8'b10001100
{
    /* Do something */;
}
else if(op == 0xAC) // 0xAC = 8'b10101100
{
   /* Do something */;
}
else if(op == 0x70) // 0x70 = 8'b01110000
{
    /* Do something */;
}
else if((op & 0xF0) == 0x90) // 0x90 = 8'b1001xxxx
{
    /* ... */
}
```

- In the first conditional you AND the input `op` with 0xFC, which is `b11111100`, in order to set the two LSB to 0, and compare it with the value you put in `casex` with the don't care bits set to 0 (0x8C)
- The second and the third conditionals are *direct comparisons*
- In the last conditional you AND the input `op` with 0xF0, which is `b11110000`, in order to set the four LSB to 0, and compare it with the value you put in `casex` with the don't care bits set to 0 (0x90)

Comment: Using logical AND like `op && 0xFC == 0x8C` is wrong because it will return only 0 or 1. `op & 0xF0 == 0x90` is also wrong because `==` operator has higher precedence then `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shift right operator (>>).

```
  int x = 10; // 1010 in binary
  switch(x >> 1) // this would have switched 101, getting rid of the 0 at the end
  switch(x >> 2) // this would have switched 10, getting rid of the 10 at the end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `gcc` family compiler (`gcc`, `clang`, `icc` etc) you can use ranges in `switch ... case` which will do what exactly you want:

```
void foo(uint8_t val)
{
    switch(val)
    {
    case 0b10001100 ... 0b10001111:
        /* do something */
        break;
    case 0b10101100:
        /* do something */
        break;
    case 0b01110000:
        /* do something */
        break;
    case 0b10010000 ... 0b10011111:
        /* do something */
        break;
    default:
        /* do something */
        break;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5f7bd9

As an additional bonus `gcc` has binary constants extension as well.